# JMS Connection Latency

Tags: networking, jboss, jms, ping, latency

I am examining an application where a JBOSS Application Server communicates with satellite JBOSS Application Servers (1 main server, hundreds of satellites).

When observing in the Windows Resource Monitor I can view the connections and see the latency by satellite - most are sub-second, but I see 10 over 1 second, of those 4 over 2 seconds and 1 over 4 seconds. This is a "moment in time" view, so as connections expire and rebuild when they need, the trend can shift. I do observe the same pair of systems have a ping latency matching seen on the connection list - so I suspect it's connection related (slow pipe, congestion, or anything in the line between points A and B).

My question is what should be a target latency, keeping in mind the satellites are VPN'd from various field sites. I use 2 seconds as a dividing line to when I need the network team to investigate, I'd like to survey what rule of thumb do you use in evaluating when the latency for a transient connection starts peaking - is it over a second? I do observe the same pair of systems have a ping latency matching seen on the connection list - so I know it's connection related.